# Show that this construction is a parallelogram.

Tags: calculus, geometry

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle. The middle of the segment $BC$ is denoted by $M$ and the centroid of $ABC$ is rated $G$.

We construct $G'$ on the line $GM$ such that $|GM|=\frac{1}{2}|GG'|$ and $|GM|=|G'M|$. In other words, $G'$ is the symmetric of $G$ with respect to $M$. 
$D$ denotes the intersection of $AB$ with $CG'$, $E$ the intersection of $DG$ with $BG'$ and $F$ the intersection of $AE$ with $CD$.

**Question:** Show that $BGCG’$ is a parallelogram.

My try : I would like to prove that $\overrightarrow{CG}=\overrightarrow{G'B}$

By the triangle medians theorem we have $\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{AC}=2\overrightarrow{AM}$, we also have $\overrightarrow{AG}=\frac{2}3\overrightarrow{AM}$ then 
$$
\overrightarrow{CG}=-\frac{2}{3}\overrightarrow{AC}+\frac{1}{3}\overrightarrow{AB}
$$

After this I tried several things like using the fact $\overrightarrow{GA}+\overrightarrow{GB}+\overrightarrow{GC}=0$ by noticing that $$\overrightarrow{G'B}=\overrightarrow{G'G}+\overrightarrow{GA}+\overrightarrow{AB}=\overrightarrow{G'G}+\overrightarrow{GA}+3\overrightarrow{CG}+\frac{2}{3}\overrightarrow{AC}$$ but I am stuck.

Comment: All that needed is to show BGCG’ is a //gm. Just drawing the pts A, B, C, M, G, and G’ will be sufficient. GG’ & BC are the diagonals of BGCG’. The fact that they bisect each other (at M) will be a sufficient reason to conclude that BGCG’ is a //gm. Thus, I don’t see how D, E, F help in getting the answer. Perhaps, the only reason to explain their presence is to act as smokies to ’complicate’ the problem. Or unless the problem has a follow-up question like requiring to prove that |DF|=|FG′|=|G′C| as shown in your further comment (asked later). You should have them included in the 1st place.

Comment: @Mick You are right, I didn't included this question because I would solve the first one in priority and add another question later but user133281 has answering my question very quickly. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the quadrilateral $BGCG'$ the intersection point $M$ of the diagonals is the midpoint of both diagonals. This implies that the quadrilateral is a parallellogram: we note that a reflection in $M$ maps $G$ to $G'$ and $B$ to $C$, which implies that the sides of the quadrilateral are pairwise equal in length and parallel.

**Edit:** A reflection in a point preserves the distance between points and the slope of lines, which shows that opposite sides of the quadrilateral are equal in length and parallel.

Alternatively, we could note that the triangles $\triangle BMG'$ and $\triangle CMG$ are congruent (by SAS), and therefore $|BG'|=|GC|$. Analogously we have $|BG|=|CG'|$. Since $\angle G'BM = GCM$, we have $BG' \parallel CG$ and similarly we find $BG \parallel CG'$.

Comment: I tried to use this propriety but it was not obvious (at least for me) the fact it implies that the sides of the quadrilateral are pairwise equal in length and parallel. How can we prove this please ?

Comment: I have expanded my answer. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: Sure, I misread the defition of a reflection.. Nice idea thanks +1 and accept.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how can I prove that $|DF|=|FG'|=|G'C|$ ?

Comment: Sure: first consider $\triangle ACD$. The line $BG$ passes through the midpoint of $AC$ and is parallel to $CD$, so $B$ is the midpoint of $AD$. Now consider triangle $\triangle ADG'$. Note that $B$ is the midpoint of $AD$ and $G$ is the midpoint of $AG'$, so $E$ is the centroid of the triangle. This implies that $AE$ is the median through $A$, thus $F$ is the midpoint of $DG'$ and $|DF|=|FG'|$. We have $2|FG'| = |DG'| = 2|BG| = 2|G'C|$, and therefore $|DF| = |FG'| = |G'C|$.

Comment: Very smart and very fast.. Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome!